# wix not updating executable

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am new to WIX. In fact, this is my first project. So it should not be surprising that I am having issues.

I had my installer all setup and ready to roll, but this morning I needed a change made to my service, so I made the change and compiled. I build the WIX project and installed it. I started my service up and ran it, but the old code was executed. As it turns out, the old version of my service is still installed. Does this mean that the new version of the service was not packaged or that there was some kind of upgrade rule that I am missing? For some reason the PDB file got updated, but not the EXE.

Below is my wxs file. Please be kind...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<?define AppName="My Service"?>
<?define MfgName="My Company"?>
<?define SourcePath="..\My Service\bin\$(var.Configuration)"?>

<Product Name="$(var.AppName)" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="$(var.MfgName)" 
       Id="*" UpgradeCode="063de86b-f12b-4af1-91ff-ce0917fffd5c" Codepage="1252">

<Package Id="*" Keywords="Installer" Description="$(var.AppName) Installer" 
         Manufacturer="$(var.MfgName)" Comments="My Service blah blah blah"
         InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" SummaryCodepage="1252" />

<!--
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
-->

<Media Id="1" Cabinet="setup.cab" EmbedCab="yes" DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1"/>
<Property Id="DiskPrompt" Value="$(var.AppName) Installer [1]"/>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
    <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="$(var.MfgName)">
              <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.AppName)">
        <Component Id="ServiceFile" Guid="3688d9ee-08ed-4dde-87d8-3b7a752a99bf">
          <File Id="ServiceEXE" Name="My Service.exe" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\My Service.exe" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" />
          <File Id="ServicePDB" Name="My Service.pdb" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\MY Service.pdb" KeyPath="no" Vital="yes"/>
          <File Id="LibraryDLL" Name="library.dll" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\library.dll" KeyPath="no" Vital="yes"/>
          <File Id="LibraryPDB" Name="library.pdb" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\library.pdb" KeyPath="no" Vital="yes"/>
          <File Id="Config" Name="My Service.exe.config" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourcePath)\My Service.exe.config" KeyPath="no" Vital="yes"/>

          <ServiceInstall Id="InstallService" Name="MyService" Type="ownProcess" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto"
                          DisplayName="$(var.AppName)" Description="My Service blah blah blah">
            <ServiceConfig OnInstall="yes" DelayedAutoStart="yes" />
          </ServiceInstall>
          <ServiceControl Id="ControlService" Name="MyService" Remove="both" Stop="both" Wait="no"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

<Feature Id="MainFeature" Title="$(var.AppName) Setup" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="ServiceFile"/>
    </Feature>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the installation was successful yet the file was not updated, you should log the install to see why. For example:

```
msiexec /i filename.msi /lvoicewarmupx log.txt
```

One reason for a file to not get updated is if Windows Installer checks the version of the existing file and it is newer than the version of the file you are trying to install.